# Does Windows Installer XML support CE installation files?

Tags: compact-framework, wix, cab

I want to know if Wix supports the CE platform.
ie based on a list of components to produce a cab file that can be installed on Win CE and/or Win Mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Wix cannot generate Windows CE CAB installer files.  Unfortunately the only thing that can do that is [cabwiz.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa924359.aspx) (I really wish they'd create an API for it).

Answer (score 1):

Not today. It's something we've thought about doing but haven't made time for... yet.

Comment: The challenge is that it's a moving target - Microsoft has changed the internals of the CAB format in the past.

Comment: Has this situation changed?